# Android emulator not displaying a TextView properly (works fine on device)

Tags: android, textview, emulation

I have a minor issue with displaying TextViews in my app while running on emulator, although everything works perfectly fine on my cell phone. I know that most of you wouldn't care about that, but I have to obtain top quality screen shots of my app (it's my project for graduation and I need those screen shots to include in the project documentation).

Those TextViews which are populated with some value in the XML layout file display properly. However, those which are populated dynamically after the user logs in (a String value from a web service) are only displayed partially, like only the top half of the line will appear, you can see it on this screen shot:

[image: link to imageshack file with screenshot]

As I mentioned, everything displays perfectly fine on my device (Samsung i5510).
Those TextViews are a part of a TableLayout and each row (static label in the left column and a dynamic value in the right one). The XML layout is as follows:

```
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/brandTableRow" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2sp" android:paddingTop="2sp">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/brandLabel" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Model pojazdu:"
                    android:layout_column="1">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/brandTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="12px"
                    android:text="" android:gravity="right">
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>             
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/widget67" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2sp" android:paddingTop="2sp">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/widget40" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ping:"
                    android:layout_column="1">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/pingTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="n/a" android:gravity="right">
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just check for the screen resolution/density of your AVD matches with your device? If not try matching the two and then see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of your padding on the textviews.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The exact same part of the line is not visible.

Comment: I see in one of your Textiviews you set the height of the textview. Try making the font smaller. It looks like its to big.

Comment: Thanks mate, it did solve the problem. For some reason I had the "12px" height hard coded for these dynamic TextViews. Changing to "wrap_content" worked. I guess the emulator had a different resolution comparing to my mobile device.

Comment: Yepa you got it =) and no problem. I make simple mistakes like this all the time. Its the fun part in coding!